# multiclients websocket application problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, websocket

I am trying to make a multi-client WebSocket application using C++, it works well on my Windows. but I have to get it to work on Linux, but something is going wrong with the `select()` function and I can't figure it out, the `select()` function doesn't detect the data from the file descriptor changing of the client, so no return from the function, it only detects the requests for connection.
Here is my code for file descriptors and the select function, if anyone can help me:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
void Server::server_connection_handle (){

    //zero the set of file descriptors
    FD_ZERO(&fr);

    FD_SET(server_sock, &fr);

      //set fd read for all client socket because we zeroed the set
      if (queue.size() > 0)  std::future <void> fu_1 =(std::async(std::launch::async, &Server::setting_file_thread, this, queue)); 
                  
    if (select(max_fd + 1, &fr,NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0){
    
        if (FD_ISSET(server_sock, &fr)){
                
            //length of the address
            int addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr);
   
            //wait until get request to accept new connection
            int cli_sock = accept(server_sock , (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addr_len);

            //test socket return success
            sock_listen->test_connection(cli_sock);

            //add client socket to queue
            queue.emplace_back(cli_sock);
            
            std::cout << "This is request to connect from ("<< cli_sock <<")and is gonna be handled" << std::endl;
        }else {
  
               std::future <void> fu_2 =(std::async(std::launch::async, &Server::recv_data, this));              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide us with more information, we don't even know what library you're using. Moreover, if you get any errors edit your post with a snapshot of the error stacktrace.

Comment: @newbie99 I put liberaries for linux, I don't have errors.  Select() doesn't recognize the data which is coming from clients it just recognizes requests on file descriptor for Server socket  for connection requests